# How to mock a dependent class without changing constructor parameters to optional in TypeScript & JEST?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, tsyringe

I'm trying to imitate something very well-known in mock practice for Java applications, but this time using TypeScript and JEST.
Suppose I have a class `Controller` who depends on a class `Service`. The `Controller` declares its dependency through the constructor, making the `Service` to be mandatory.
I use a Dependency Injection (DI) library (`tsyringe`) to resolve the dependencies in runtime, therefore the DI container will take care of creating an instance of the `Service` and injecting it into the `Controller` when the time comes.

For clarity, here it goes the source code for the `Controller`:

```js
import { scoped, Lifecycle } from "tsyringe";
import { RouteService } from "./RouteService";
import { RouteDTO } from "./view/RouteDTO";

@scoped(Lifecycle.ContainerScoped)
export class RouteController {

    constructor(private routeService: RouteService) {}

    public createRoute(route: RouteDTO): RouteDTO {
        // business logic subject for testing
        if (isBusinessLogicValid) {
            return this.routeService.saveRoute(route);
        } else {
            throw Error("Invalid business logic");
        }
    }
}
```

and here goes the source code for the `Service`:

```js
import { scoped, Lifecycle } from "tsyringe";
import { UserSession } from "../user/UserSession";
import { RouteDTO } from "./view/RouteDTO";

@scoped(Lifecycle.ContainerScoped)
export class RouteService {

    constructor(
        private userSession: UserSession
    ) {}

    public saveRoute(route: RouteDTO): RouteDTO {
        // business logic and persistence
        return route
    }

}
```

I'm trying to mock the class `RouteService` in a way so that I don't need to create an instance of it manually to unit test the `RouteController`, otherwise, I'll need to resolve all downstream dependencies (meaning: `RouteController` depends on `RouteService`, `RouteService` depends on `UserSession`, `UserSession` depends on ...).
In Java using Mockito I'd be able to do something like this:

```java
RouteService routeServiceMock = mock(RouteService.class); // this'd be the goal
// mock definitions on routeServiceMock
RouteController controller = new RouteController(routeServiceMock);
RouteDTO newDTO = createRouteDTO();
RouteDTO savedDTO = controller.save(newDTO);
assertThat(savedDTO).isEqualsTo(newDTO);
//... other assertions
```

I've been looking at Jest documentation and I couldn't find anything equivalent. Does anybody know if such a thing is feasiable? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: I can't post this as a full answer but I could suggest you take a look at `ts-mockito` for mocking and `iti` for DI. My opinion that it will be simpler. Disclaimer: I was sick of `tsyringe` issues and wrote an `iti` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found a workable solution for a while, but I'm not very happy with the structure of the solution. Basically, I have to double cast it `as unknown as RouteService`.

I can do the following:

```js
describe('Route controller test', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        let routeServiceMock: RouteService = {
            saveRoute: jest.fn(async route => route)
        } as unknown as RouteService
        routeController = new RouteController(routeServiceMock);
    })

   // ...
}
```